# AutoMapper How to map one class to another class in a ForMember method

Tags: c#, automapper

So I have got this class structure for my project:

```
public class SomeType {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<Customer> Customers {get; set;}
}

public class Customer {
     public int Id {get; set;}
     public string FirstName {get; set;}
}

public class CustomerDto {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
}

public class SomeTypeDto {
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public List<object> SomeValues {get; set;}
}
```

At some point in my project I call it like this:

```
var result = _mapper.Map<SomeTypeDto>(someType);
```

Is there a way to convert the list of type Customer to a list of type CustomerDto upon mapping the SomeType class to SomeTypeDto with AutoMapper? I remember there was a way before with the static Mapper.Map<>() method called inside a MapFrom method when creating the types mapping but it doesn't seem to work with the newer versions.

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Nested-mappings.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MapperConfiguration` / (Mapping) `Profile` should look as below:

> MapperConfiguration

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>();

    cfg.CreateMap<SomeType, SomeTypeDto>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.SomeValues, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Customers));
});
```

> MappingProfile

```cs
public class SomeTypeProfile : Profile
{
    public SomeTypeProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>();

        CreateMap<SomeType, SomeTypeDto>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.SomeValues, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Customers));
    }
}
```

---

```cs
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerDto>();

    cfg.CreateMap<SomeType, SomeTypeDto>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.SomeValues, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Customers));
});
        
IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        
var someType = new SomeType 
{ 
    Id = 1, 
    Customers = new List<Customer> 
    { 
        new Customer { Id = 1, FirstName = "Alfred" } ,
        new Customer { Id = 2, FirstName = "Max" } 
    } 
};

var someTypeDto = mapper.Map<SomeType, SomeTypeDto>(someType);
```

[Sample Demo on .Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Y2hrU4)